# Clarification on VPN Traffic Segregation in Android Work Profile

Tags: android, vpn, android-work-profile

I'd like to confirm whether Android imposes the restriction that a VPN running in the work profile can only handle traffic originating from within the work profile. Does this mean that traffic from the personal profile remains separate and is not routed through the VPN in the work profile?

Thank you.

I did checked some official Android documentation but none states this in a straight forward manner